# Блок с движущимися анимированными элементами

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, css-animation

На странице есть блок с категориями брендов. На изображении привел пример, для понимания как это примерно выглядит. Голубые блоки это сами div'ы с картинками внутри, зеленый пунктир - это ось по которой должны двигаться элементы, красный прямоугольник - это область в которую попадает текущий блок и он увеличивается находясь в этой области. По идее блоки начинают вращаться в момент загрузки страницы, когда юзер подводит курсор к левой стороне - элементы вращаются по часовой стрелке, и к правой - наоборот.

Дело в том, что я не работал никогда с анимацией, подскажите куда рыть чтобы запилить это, или может быть есть что-то реализованное и можно адаптировать это под себя?

[image: css анимация блоков]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю кустарное решение.
Заключается в css анимации и периодической проверке позиции элементов.
js кода не так много:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var blocks = $('.container .block'),
      c = 0,
      len = blocks.length;

  // просто запустим анимацию поочереди
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
      blocks.eq(c).addClass('animate');
      c++;
      if(c >= len) clearInterval(interval);
  }, 1500);

  // запомним позицию элемента, внутри которого надо увеличить блоки
  var target = $('.container .target'),
      tLeft = target.position().left,
      tRight = tLeft+target.width(),
      tTop = target.position().top,
      tBottom = tTop+target.height();

  // запускаем периодическую проверку позиций блоков.
  setInterval(function(){
    blocks.each(function(){
      // вычислим позицию блока
      var lpos = $(this).position().left,
            tpos = $(this).position().top;
      // проверим входит внутрь или нет
      if(lpos > tLeft && lpos < tRight && tpos > tTop && tpos < tBottom) $(this).addClass('focus');
      else $(this).removeClass('focus');
    });
  }, 100); // если блоки будут двигаться достаточно медленно, можно установить период подлиннее, чтобы облегчить работу браузеру
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m0wtsz00/ (Увиденное может как развеселить так и опечалить)
Анимация крайне примерная, можно сделать намного изящнее, но идею уловить можно.

Нехорошо то, что браузер напрягается. Но может быть я и преувеличил.

UPD:
Можно вообще настроить отображение (увеличение) внутри блока `@keyframes circle` https://jsfiddle.net/m0wtsz00/3/ и вовсе обойтись без js (или почти без js).

Answer (score 4):

Вот схожая [идея](http://www.03www.ru/css-2011/240211-020.html). Немного доработать перемещение блоков, и в целом будет готово.

```js
  // DOM готова
  $(function() {

    var current;

    function rotate() {

      // Выглядит ужасно, но классы должны быть использованы в определенном порядке

      if (current == 1) {
        $("#block-1").removeClass().addClass("active");
        $("#block-2").removeClass().addClass("non-active-top");
        $("#block-3").removeClass().addClass("non-active-bottom");
      } else if (current == 2) {
        $("#block-1").removeClass().addClass("non-active-bottom");
        $("#block-2").removeClass().addClass("active");
        $("#block-3").removeClass().addClass("non-active-top");
      } else {
        $("#block-1").removeClass().addClass("non-active-top");
        $("#block-2").removeClass().addClass("non-active-bottom");
        $("#block-3").removeClass().addClass("active");
      }

    }

    $("#rotator div").click(function() {

      current = this.id.substr(6);
      rotate();

    });

  });
```

```css
#rotator {
  width: 920px;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
#block-1 {
  background: #d5fcff;
}
#block-2 {
  background: #e1ffd5;
}
#block-3 {
  background: #ffffd8;
}
#rotator > div {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#rotator > div > div {
  padding: 20px;
}
#rotator > div > div img {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 2px 10px;
}
#rotator .active {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 580px;
  height: 280px;
}
#rotator .non-active-top {
  top: 20px;
  left: 620px;
  height: 130px;
  width: 320px;
}
#rotator .non-active-bottom {
  top: 170px;
  left: 620px;
  height: 130px;
  width: 320px;
}
#rotator .non-active-top:hover,
#rotator .non-active-bottom:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#rotator h2 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 130px;
}
#rotator .active h2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-wrap">

  <h1>Вращающиеся блоки</h1>
  <p>Нажмите на маленьком блоке справа для вращения.</p>
  <div id="rotator">

    <div id="block-1" class="active">
      <h2>Подзаголовок #1</h2>
      <div>
        <h1>Семь лягушек-космонавтов высадились на Луне!</h1>
        <img src="spacefrog.jpg" alt="space frog">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="block-2" class="non-active-top">
      <h2>Подзаголовок #2</h2>
      <div>
        <h1>Сила вуду! Будешь пробовать? Я буду.</h1>
        <img src="goblins.jpg" alt="goblins">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="block-3" class="non-active-bottom">
      <h2>Подзаголовок #3</h2>
      <div>
        <h1>Внезапно вы можете понять, что живете в лачуге</h1>
        <p>text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/73142)

Comment: Добавил пример кода